# What Percentile Do I fall in with this test score vs average?

Tags: statistics

I just took an online test and I was notified that the average score for the test was 45% (out of 100%) and I received a 72%.

Using these 2 pieces of information would it be possible to calculate under what percentile I fall for test scores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that would not be possible without further information about the distribution.
Consider for example a situation where there were only 2 students, you got 72 and the other person got 18.  In that case you did the best.
Consider another alternative where two people got 0, you got 72, and 2 people got 73.  In that case, you were right in the middle of the pack.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly impossible. To appreciate this just consider two possible scenarios of 100 people having taken the test so far.

- 100 scored 45%
- 45 scored 100%, 55 scored 0%

In the first case you are the best, in the second a bit above average.